# How can I search for an event WITHOUT a specific extended attribute using the Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

Is there a way to search for a calendar event that does not have a specific shared extended property set?

Using sharedExtendedProperty, I can search for calendar events containing a specific value for an extended property, such as sharedExtendedProperty="student_id=500" will bring back all calendar events where the shared extended property student_id is 500.

But I can't find any way to search for events where the same property hasn't been set yet.  Is there a way to do this?

As an example, consider the three events below.  I want to execute a search that will bring back any event that does not have the extended property "student_id". So "training 2" and "training 3" should be returned, but not "training 1".

```
{
    "summary": "training 1",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-02T09:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-02T11:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "extendedProperties": {
        "shared": {
            "student_id": "56a71d61c17c248729c9b815"
        }
    }
}

{
    "summary": "training 2",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-04T09:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-04T11:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "extendedProperties": {
        "shared": {
            "course_type": "internal"
        }
    }
}

{
    "summary": "training 3",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-06T09:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2016-08-06T11:00:00-07:00"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## Search an event without using [sharedExtendedProperty](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters)

It is possible, just check the different parameters that you can use in the event list. And just take note that `sharedExtendedProperty` is just an optional parameter, so you can search for an event without this.

## Alternative function for sharedExtendedProperty in searching for events.

I think there is no alternative way or do the same function of this in searching for events. The google creates this for you to search events based on the values of their [extended properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties). So if you want to search event like this, you will have no choice but to use this parameter.

Comment: To clarify, I am not looking for a way to search without using the sharedExtendedProperty, I want to search for events that don't have the specific sharedExtendedProperty set excluding the events that do.

Comment: I can't understand your question, can you clarify it more.. and if you have sample request, can you provide it also.

Comment: I've added an example for clarification.  I would happy to provide any other details that would be helpful, but don't know what you're looking for.